# Cannot open PDF in iBooks on Mac

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, pdf, books

on MacI sync my PDF files normally between my Mac and my iPhone and iPad. Bookmarks and resume options are working between iOS devices for epubs. However, no PDF can be opened in iBooks on Mac — it gets opened in Preview.app instead and bookmarks and resume aren’t working (while they still do work between iOS devices).

Is there a way to read PDF in iBooks on Mac? Or at least enable the bookmarks and resume for it on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Considering Preview.app to be mediocre as a PDF viewer (and that's a compliment for it), you might use Adobe Reader on the Mac; this should maintain the annotations (not tested, however).